# How to write down this cadenza in Musescore?

Tags: musescore, mozart, cadenza

I am arranging Mozart's Sonata in C minor for a string trio, and I am almost done writing down the second movement. But there are 2 cadenzas that I don't understand how to write down. I can do long tuplets no problem and I used this method to write down 3 cadenzas before in Musescore(and these cadenzas are in the same sonata). But those 3 cadenzas had eighth rests as a reference value in the staff above or below. These 2 cadenzas that I haven't written down, don't have any rests as a reference value.

Here is the first of the cadenzas(for reference, the key signature is 3 flats here and it is the second movement of the sonata):

[image]

**How am I supposed to get that across in Musescore? I mean the cadenza starting after the first set of sixteenths and ending before the rest of the sixteenths? Do I just add a 9/8 time signature around here to get an eighth rest for reference as the length of the cadenza and then make the time signatureand eighth rest invisible? Or is there a different way to get across the cadenza without any overlapping with the sixteenths?**

Answer (score 4):

Here's how I created this bar:

1. Enter the standard notes:

   [image]
2. Select the last three treble clef notes, and press `ctrl` + `shift` + `down (arrow)` to move them to the bar below.

[image]

3. With the G selected, add 15 grace notes:

   [image]
4. Use `ctrl` to select the last 12 notes, and click on the 'hemidemisemiquaver' button (or type `1`)

   [image]
5. Move to the correct place, and add a slur, and move the rests:

   [image]

Comment: But that would cause it to overlap with the second set of sixteenths, which isn't the way Mozart himself wrote the cadenza if you look at the image in my question(I'm sticking to Mozart as much as I can in this sonata arrangement).

Comment: @Caters Amended - is this correct?

Comment: I exported the MusicXML here: https://paste.ee/p/OzVjH

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: Please may I have a green tick? 

Comment: Here you go: ✔️